# Are there two Raynauds?

Tags: ho.history-overview

The [Wikipedia page on Michel Raynaud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michel_Raynaud) says that he worked with Grothendieck on the SGA volumes. However, in SGA 1 and 2 the name Mme Michèle Raynaud is given. According to the [Genealogy Project](http://genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=31245), the two are different persons, but I cannot find any further information on Michèle Raynaud. Are there really two Raynauds, or did Michèle Raynaud just become Michel Raynaud at some point?

Comment: Hilarious. Why should Raynaud have written two dissertations?

Comment: There are two. They are in fact married! Is this question really appropriate for MO? Maybe.

Comment: Martin Brandenburg, it is not impossible that somebody writes two dissertations. In particular, certain academic systems have (or had) a 'second dissertation';  resembling 'Doktorat' and then 'Habilitation' (in the German context). And, I believe, that in particular the French system had at some point (though rather slightly later than the time in question) two types of dissertations in parallel (3eme cycle and d'Etat). So, in principle one could imagine that one person had two thesis and there is an error in the database.

Comment: http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~mitya/langlands/reminiscences1.pdf is a pretty interesting discussion of Grothendieck from a student's perspective. Definitely the two Raynauds were married.

Comment: and still are married!

Comment: "did Michèle Raynaud just become Michel Raynaud at some point?" As neither "Michèle" nor "Michel" is an epicene name in French, I'm sure wikipedia would have noted such a drastic change.

Answer (score 2):

While Kevin Buzzard's comment is more informative than what I could come up with (not knowing the involved persons) here is some generally accessible information showing that there is a Michèle and a Michel.

First, the MathSciNet author database lists both (and MathSciNet is very good at 'merging' different names even pseudonyms under which one and the same person published).

Second, and more significantly, during a period of several years, sixties/seventies, one can find a variety of papers published by Michèle Raynaud as well as papers published by Michel Raynaud.

For example:

> Raynaud, Michèle Théorèmes de Lefschetz en cohomologie étale des faisceaux en groupes non nécessairement commutatifs. (French)  C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris Sér. A-B  270  1970
>
> Raynaud, Michel Anneaux locaux henséliens. (French) Lecture Notes in Mathematics, Vol. 169 Springer-Verlag, Berlin-New York 1970

Comment: Or simply compare http://www.academie-sciences.fr/academie/membre/Raynaud_Michel.htm with http://wwww.math.polytechnique.fr/~laszlo/sga2/sga2-smf.pdf 

Comment: Well, except if I am missing something in the second link (which by the way has one w too much), your information merely repeats what the questioner already knew.